# STM32H7 HAL read GPIOC13 with DMA into SRAM

Tags: stm32, timer, gpio, hal

I am trying to read GPIO pins (on row C) with DMA into SRAM, using TIM1 as clock. I am using an STM32H750B-DK

When TIM1 goes high, DMA should read from GPIO to SRAM continuously (until it's stopped by a user).

Here is what I tried so far to read GPIOC with 1 MHz and then check if PIN 13 (blue button) is high:

**main.c**

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header */
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2023 STMicroelectronics.
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * This software is licensed under terms that can be found in the LICENSE file
  * in the root directory of this software component.
  * If no LICENSE file comes with this software, it is provided AS-IS.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* USER CODE END Header */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include "usart.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1000 // Adjust buffer size as needed
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */
#ifdef __GNUC__
/* With GCC, small printf (option LD Linker->Libraries->Small printf
   set to 'Yes') calls __io_putchar() */
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int __io_putchar(int ch)
#else
#define PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE int fputc(int ch, FILE *f)
#endif /* __GNUC__ */
/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim1;
DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim1_up;
uint32_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};                     // Buffer to store data

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void);
static void MX_DMA_Init(void);
/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Private user code ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  * @retval int
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  BSP_LED_Init(LED_RED);
  BSP_LED_Init(LED_GREEN);
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();
  printf("Booting Program\n");

  // Disable Direct Mode for DMA2 Stream 5
  //HAL_DMAEx_DisableDirectMode(&hdma_tim1_up);

  // Set FIFO threshold for DMA2 Stream 5
  //HAL_DMAEx_SetFifoThreshold(&hdma_tim1_up, DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL);

  /* Start the DMA transfer */
  HAL_DMA_Start(htim1.hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE], (uint32_t)&GPIOC->IDR, (uint32_t)&buffer, 512);
  //HAL_DMA_Start(&hdma_tim1_up, (uint32_t)(&GPIOC->IDR), (uint32_t)(buffer), 512);

  /* Start the timer */
  HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim1);

  /* Wait for the transfer to complete */
  //It cannot be used in Circular mode sadly :(
  //HAL_DMA_PollForTransfer(&hdma_tim1_up, HAL_DMA_FULL_TRANSFER, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  //HAL_DMA_Abort(&hdma_tim1_up);
  //HAL_DMA_DeInit(&hdma_tim1_up);

  /* Process the data in the SRAM buffer */
  //HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&buffer, 512, 0xFFFF);
  //for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
  //{
    // Process the data here
    // ...
  //}
  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
      /*
      if (data & GPIO_PIN_13) {
          // GPIOC13 is high
        printf("User button: 1\n");
      } else {
        // GPIOC13 is low
          printf("User button: 0\n");
      }
      */

      //printf("Buffer content: %d\n", buffer[0]);
      //printf("Timer 1 value: %d\n", TIM1->CNT);  //Timer is working and counting fine
/*
      if (buffer & GPIO_PIN_13) {
          // GPIOC13 is high
        printf("User button: 1\n");
      } else {
        // GPIOC13 is low
          printf("User button: 0\n");
      }*/

      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&buffer, 512, 0xFFFF); //There is always 0 (I thought that one pin should be 1 if I press or keep pressing USER BUTTON

    HAL_Delay(100);
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Supply configuration update enable
  */
  HAL_PWREx_ConfigSupply(PWR_LDO_SUPPLY);

  /** Configure the main internal regulator output voltage
  */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);

  while(!__HAL_PWR_GET_FLAG(PWR_FLAG_VOSRDY)) {}

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D3PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_D1PCLK1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB3CLKDivider = RCC_APB3_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_APB1_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_APB2_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB4CLKDivider = RCC_APB4_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 1 */
  htim1.Instance = TIM1;
  htim1.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim1.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim1.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim1.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim1.Init.RepetitionCounter = 0;
  htim1.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim1, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_ENABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /*
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger2 = TIM_TRGO2_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim1, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }*/
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * Enable DMA controller clock
  */
static void MX_DMA_Init(void)
{

  /* DMA controller clock enable */
  __HAL_RCC_DMA2_CLK_ENABLE();

  /* DMA interrupt init */
  /* DMA2_Stream5_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA2_Stream5_IRQn, 0, 0);
  HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA2_Stream5_IRQn);

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

      /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();

      /*Configure GPIO pin : PC13 */
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = B1_Pin;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT;
      GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
      HAL_GPIO_Init(B1_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct); //User Button is on PIOC PIN 13
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
/**
  * @brief  Retargets the C library printf function to the USART.
  * @param  None
  * @retval None
  */
PUTCHAR_PROTOTYPE
{
  /* Place your implementation of fputc here */
  /* e.g. write a character to the USART2 and Loop until the end of transmission */
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, (uint8_t *)&ch, 1, 0xFFFF);

  return ch;
}
/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */
```

**stm32h7xx_hal_msp.c**

```
/* USER CODE END Includes */
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_tim1_up;

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock enable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* TIM1 DMA Init */
    /* TIM1_UP Init */
    hdma_tim1_up.Instance = DMA2_Stream5;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.Request = DMA_REQUEST_TIM1_UP;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.Direction = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.PeriphInc = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.MemInc = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.MemDataAlignment = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.Mode = DMA_CIRCULAR;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.Priority = DMA_PRIORITY_VERY_HIGH;
    hdma_tim1_up.Init.FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
    if (HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_tim1_up) != HAL_OK)
    {
      Error_Handler();
    }

    __HAL_LINKDMA(htim_base,hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE],hdma_tim1_up);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspInit 1 */
  }

}

void HAL_TIM_Base_MspDeInit(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim_base)
{
  if(htim_base->Instance==TIM1)
  {
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspDeInit 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspDeInit 0 */
    /* Peripheral clock disable */
    __HAL_RCC_TIM1_CLK_DISABLE();

    /**TIM1 GPIO Configuration
    PA8     ------> TIM1_CH1
    */
    HAL_GPIO_DeInit(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8);

    /* TIM1 DMA DeInit */
    HAL_DMA_DeInit(htim_base->hdma[TIM_DMA_ID_UPDATE]);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_MspDeInit 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM1_MspDeInit 1 */
  }

}
```

**stm32h7xx_it.c**

```
/**
  * @brief This function handles DMA2 stream5 global interrupt.
  */
void DMA2_Stream5_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream5_IRQn 0 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream5_IRQn 0 */
  HAL_DMA_IRQHandler(&hdma_tim1_up);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN DMA2_Stream5_IRQn 1 */

  /* USER CODE END DMA2_Stream5_IRQn 1 */
}
```

Unfortionatly, I can't get this to work, because it seems the user button is never high, even if I press it (and 1 MHz should be plenty fast for my slow button press).

This example is only for one pin, but at the end I would like to read 4 pins continuously.

I would really like to use HAL, because then this code would be more portable between STM families.

The UART is not important in this example, I only use it for debugging

I hope someone can tell me what I am doing wrong, and why my example doesn't work.

Maybe I should use a second timer (TIM8) to count like 2 samples and only display that, I don't know; am I displaying to many samples and is that why nothing works?

Comment: Narrow the problem down. You have (at least) 3 different subsystems running, and it's not clear which of them is failing. Have you configured GPIOC correctly? Do you read pins going high if you just read the port manually? What about the timer? How do you know that it is configured correctly & running? Maybe enable the timer interrupt and use it to toggle a pin or something like that to check. Does the DMA actually run? Do you get a Transfer-Complete interrupt from it? Do you see the DMA_S5NDTR register decrement down from the number you asked for (512) to 0?

Comment: GPIO works (I tried reading direcly from GPIOC->IDR),
Timer runs (I read TIM1->CNT)
Timer interupts also work, will check DMA

Comment: I checked DMA2_Stream5->NDTR and it has value 16 in it, but it does not decrease at all (is this because of circular mode?)